# How can I find intersection with the y-axis of fitted double gaussian

Tags: python, curve-fitting, gaussian, data-fitting

I have fitted my data with a double Gaussian and now I have to find where the constant area under this fit is intersecting the y - axis. for better understanding of what I am talking and searching for I provide my code plus picture. here in the first block there is just the fit function for my double Gaussian.

```
# this is my fit function 
def func(x, *params):
y = np.zeros_like(x)

for i in range(0, len(params), 3):
    ctr = params[i]
    amp = params[i+1]
    wid = params[i+2]
    y = y + amp * np.exp( -((x - ctr)/wid)**2) + amp * np.exp( -((x - 
    ctr+180)/wid)**2)
 return y
```

Then I'm just importing the data from an external csv file with values in two columns and addressing them to x and y, guess are my starting parameters for the fit

```
data=np.loadtxt("test.csv")
x= data[:,0]
y= data[:,1]
guess = [20, 0.7, 30, 210, 0.7, 30, 300, 0.05, 10]


popt, pcov = curve_fit(func, x, y, p0=guess)
fit1 = func(x, *popt)
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.plot(x, fit1 , 'r-')
plt.show()
```

What I am receiving then is this fit:

[image: fit]

The question now is how I can find this intersection or how can I calculate the area under the double Gaussian? (I have marked it in this picture with the green line, so I am searching for this area or at least where this line is intersecting the y axis):

[image: intersection]

Do you have any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: If in your equation you include an offset, with initial parameter estimate of min(y), does it give the value as part of the fit? This should be easy to test.